# compare 2 unix files which has different number format

Tags: unix, comparison

i need to compare selected fields of 2 flat files in UNIX.

the file 1 has the amount in following  format

-0

-0.0

1.2

0.0

1

the file 2 has the amount in the following order

0.00

0.00

1.20

0.00

1.00

can you help in comparing these 2 files

i used cut command to get desired field to compare

cut -d '|' -f 1-45,56,67-174 filename

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. i dont completely understand the output you are looking for.

From what i get, you want to compare values like 1.2 to 1.20 and that should not spit out as a difference. If that is right, you can transform the values in file 1 using the bc command and then compare to values in file 2. Example:

```
echo "1.2 * 1.00" | bc

Output: 1.20
```

Comment: i have a file
1|2.3|2.3|34
1|0|0|34
1|0.0|0.0|34
1|11|11|34
1|.3|.3|34
1|-0.00|-0.00|34
1|1.67|1.67|34




I need it to convert it into this
1|2.30|2.30|34
1|0.00|0.00|34
1|0.00|0.00|34
1|11.00|11.00|34
1|0.30|0.30|34
1|0.00|0.00|34
1|1.67|1.67|34



i used the following but the last value came as



1|1.70|1.70|34








awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="|"} {$2=$2+0.00;$3=$3+0.00; print $0 }' file1 > temp1

awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="|"} {$2=sprintf("%.2f",$2);$3=sprintf("%.2f",$3);print $0}' temp1 > temp2

Comment: I put together a quick code to take care of this. may not be optimized
    awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="|"} {for (i =1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^[0.00-9.00]+$/ ){$i=sprintf("%0.2f",$i)};print $0}' file1

output:
1.00|2.30|2.30|34 1|0.00|0.00|34 1|0.00|0.00|34 1|11.00|11.00|34 1|0.30|0.30|34 1|-0.00|-0.00|34 1|1.67|1.67|34.00